# How to change the format of table captions?

Tags: tables, captions, ctable

[image: sample]

How I can change "Table 1: sample" to "Table 1. sample"?

PS. I'm using ctable, if it important:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ctable}
\begin{document}
\ctable
[caption={sample}]
{|l|r|}
{}
{
  \hline
  test & some example stuff \\ \hline
  \hline
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `caption` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage[labelsep=period]{caption}

\begin{document}
\ctable
[caption={sample}]
{|l|r|}
{}
{
  \hline
  test & some example stuff \\ \hline
  \hline
}
\end{document}
```

If you want the change to *only* apply to `ctable`, a bit more setup is required:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{caption}

\makeatletter
\preto\@ctblCaption{\captionsetup{labelsep=period}}
\makeatother
```